# Slow execution of queries on a Microsoft Access database via ADO .Net

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, odbc

I am reimplementing a C++ layer into a C# layer at my company.
SQL queries are executed in the layer on a Microsoft Access database via an ODBC datasource.
The database is a .mdb file and the ODBC datasource uses the following driver : Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb).

The C++ layer uses the Windows ODBC API to execute SQL queries via the ODBC datasource.
For instance the SQLExecDirect function is called to execute a SQL query.

The C# layer uses the ADO .Net OdbcConnection class to execute SQL queries via the ODBC datasource.

The execution of several SQL queries takes less than 1 minute when using the C++ layer.
The execution of the same SQL queries takes approximatively 20 minutes when using the C# layer.
Does anyone know why the execution is slower when using the C# layer ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: No, should not be. Can we have a sample of the queries showing this behavior? Have you profiled that it is a data access issue (i.e. not the processing behind)?

Comment: It is generally much faster to use DAO (please note this is not old technology) than ADO when working with MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found why the execution of queries was slow when using the C# layer.
I forgot to dispose the IDbCommand objects.